# Spark SQL single quote error

Tags: java, sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame (Apache Spark 1.5).
I want add new column using spark sql context to get new column where all raws contains a single quote.

My code:

```
df.registerTempTable("tempdf");
df = df.sqlContext().sql("SELECT *, \" \\\" \" as quoteCol FROM tempdf");
```

After execution Spark throw next exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.44] failure: ``union'' expected but ErrorToken(end of input) found

SELECT *, " \" " as quoteCol FROM tempdf
                                        ^
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefaultParserDialect.parse(ParserDialect.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:113)
    at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:137)
    ...
```

Next code work correctly and add new row with a single character:

```
df.registerTempTable("tempdf");
df = df.sqlContext().sql("SELECT *, \" q \" as quoteCol FROM tempdf");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

SQL strings should use single quotes:

```
sqlContext().sql("SELECT *, '\"' AS quoteCol FROM tempdf");
```

Comment: Next expression will cause same exception:


`SELECT *, ' \' ' as quoteCol FROM tempdf`


I understand that I can not use quotation marks inside the same quote that outside them?

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Better try it this way it will ignore the quotes included in the String. It should improve the readability:

```
dfs = sqlContext().sql("""SELECT *, '\"' AS quoteCol FROM tempdf""");
```